# Dynamic loading of Maven artifacts at runtime

Tags: maven, aether

At runtime my app would like to add functionality dynamically. We'd like to be able to download artifacts from a Maven repo, add them to the classpath, and use them without doing an app server restart. Possible?

I have come across Eclipse Aether, which give programmatic access to Maven repos. Now the missing piece is the dynamic classpath.

Comment: The question is why do you need that?

Comment: To make it easier to deploy code across a cluser of machines. If I could deploy an artifact to a repo, and then send a simple command to each machine on the cluster to grab the code and start using it, it would be very cool.

Answer (score 2):

Aether from Sonatype is what you need. Try to use [jcabi-aether](http://aether.jcabi.com/), which is a wrapper around Aether:

```
File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

All you need to know is a list of remote Maven repositories, a local repo location, and Maven coordinates of the artifact to start with.

Comment: Does this solve the classloader issue? Will it add the artifacts to a classloader so I can use the in my app?

Comment: No, it just loads JAR files from the network to your local disc

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but aether is a great idea. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using a commercial product, one option is [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/)